# Test coverage in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

Is there any way that can be used to find out the code coverage of a Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: honestly, I don't know why this question was even closed in the first place as it looks legit to me. This thread ranks #2 in DuckDuckGo for the query `rails test coverage gem`, so it would have greatly helped me to find good and updated results instead of a closed question.
Which guidelines is it breaking anyway? It would be good to know that as well instead of just being trigger happy and closing everything that lacks a comma.
@spickermann , 
@Mark Rotteveel , 
@Holger Just , 
@Magnilex , 
@freefaller

Comment: @Salomanuel Close voters don't get notified of pings like that. Note that this question is a bit broad, and is likely to invite suggestions for tools (as some answers have already done). SO is not really the right platform to get suggestions for tools; asking how to use a specific tool to do a specific task is fine.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases the best code coverage solution for Rails is SimpleCov.

Rcov is quite outdated now, because it doesn't work well with Ruby 1.9 and above.

Also, if you are interested in Mutation testing you should take a look at [mutant gem](https://github.com/mbj/mutant).

> The idea is that if code can be changed and your tests do not notice, then either that code isn't being covered or it does not have a speced side effect.

Right now it supports only RSpec. The Minitest integration is still in the works.

Here is a great [article](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/06/how-good-are-your-ruby-tests-testing-your-tests-with-mutant/) about it. 
Basically, Rcov and SimpleCov only check line coverage.

> Mutation testing takes your code and your tests. It parses the code to the Abstract Syntax Tree. It changes the nodes of the tree (mutates). It does it in memory. As a result we now have a mutant - a mutated version of your code... The idea here is that the tests should kill the mutant. Killing the mutant happens when tests fail for a mutated code. Killing all mutants means that you have a 100% test coverage. It means that you have tests for all of your code details. This means you can safely refactor and your tests are really covering you.

Answer (score 2):

The best two gems out there for test coverage are SimpleCov and Rcov. You can also use [coveralls.io](http://coveralls.io) for a hosted solution with GitHub support.